# Splitting a bit array in Verilog

Tags: algorithm, verilog

I am designing a basic AES algorithm on verilog, and I need to split a 128 bits array into 16 parts each one of 8 bits.

For example (basic 8 bit example), if I receive 10111011 I need to generate 4 outputs 10 11 10 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A double packed array works:

```
reg [127:0] in;
wire [15:0] [7:0] out_1 = in; // msb in entry 15
wire [0:15] [7:0] out_2 = in; // msb in entry 0
```

If only one byte is needed to be read at a time, it can be done Verilog-2001 or SystemVerilog as:

```
reg [127:0] in;
reg [3:0] idx;
wire [7:0] out = in[8*idx +: 8];
```

Answer (score 5):

Retrieving bytes from an array is straight forward:

```
module huge_array (
  input [128-1:0] data
);
  wire [7:0] first_byte,
  assign first_byte = data[7:0];

  wire [7:0] second_byte,
  assign second_byte = data[8*2-1:8*1];
endmodule
```

It would be much easier if the data was formatted into a memory.

```
module huge_array2 (
  input [7:0] data [0:16]
);
  wire [7:0] first_byte,
  assign first_byte = data[0];

  wire [7:0] second_byte,
  assign second_byte = data[1];
endmodule
```